# JS RegExp Issue

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate an email address and using a regex like that:

```
\b[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]+\b/i
```

Tests on regexr.com tell that it works as intended, but when I'm trying to do like this:

```
var a = new RegExp("\b[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]+\b/i");
console.log(a.test("foo@bar.com"));
```

I get `false`. What am I doing wrong? Is that regexp wrong or, maybe, there's some problem because of constructing it using constructor or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor you do **not** include the flags nor the forward slashes in the string. You would also need to escape any backslashes as normal string escape rules apply.

```js
var a = new RegExp("\\b[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]+\\b", 'i');
document.write('<pre>' + a.test("foo@bar.com") + '</pre>');
```

That said, unless you are using a dynamically generated pattern that will be set at runtime you should use the literal regexp notation instead if it is constant.

```js
var a = /\b[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]+\b/i;
document.write('<pre>' + a.test("foo@bar.com") + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I've forgot to emphasize, yes, the idea is to create regexp dynamically from string. How can I make it work that way?

Comment: If you are making a dynamic pattern that will need to be updated at runtime rather than eval time you can use the `RegExp` constructor. But as stated above you do **not** include the forward slashes nor the flags in the string.

Comment: This won't work because you need double back-slashes.

Comment: @torazaburo Seems to make it work. Could you plz explain, why do I need to escape backslashes when using constructor, but I don't need to do that if I'm using a regexp literal?

Comment: @TristanTzara It's because with the `RegExp` constructor normal string escape rules apply. That includes the special character classes.